# Injected ServetContext is null on Grizzly, not null in TomCat 7

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, servlets, grizzly

I'm working on a Jax-RS RESTful web-service. While I'm still coding (in Eclipse), I'd like to be able to debug easily, so I decided to have a Maven project and I use dependencies to the Grizzly web server, allowing me to start up a server with merely 2 lines of code (not even having to build the WAR file).

In my web-service implementation class (the one with @Path) I have injected the context as member variable:

```
@javax.ws.rs.core.Context
ServletContext context;
```

When I check the context variable for null, it will not be null if I build the WAR file and deploy it in TomCat, but it will be null when I start my Grizzly server and check it then. Starting the Grizzly v1.9 server is done as follows:

```
String url = "http://localhost:1234";
SelectorThread srv = GrizzlyServerFactory.create(url);
```

I've tried to find solutions to this with Google, someone suggested to enable "load-on-startup" in the web.xml, but this didn't help either.

Any ideas?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answer here made some sense, I wasn't too sure, because according to the maven dependency tree, the servlet package was also included.

I could fix the problem by migrating to a different maven dependency. I'm now using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and followed the instructions of http://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/jersey_grizzly_2_x_integration (Sample) to make it work. The servlet context is now successfully injected.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you use Grizzly without the Servlet Container extension. Theoretically JAX-RS may run not only on servlet environment, but then you cannot get the ServletContext or HttpServletRequest or Response.